# FireFox displaying an unexpected error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

Hi guys i am working on the drawing application. I have completed the application but it is not working on the FireFox properly it is showing as unexpected error i.e. image of a explanation. 
Can anyone help me to figure out this error.

here is the image of the error screen:
[image: Fire fox error screen]

Comment: You need to supply more detail. Perhaps an image of whats going on or the details of the error.

Comment: Also try installing flashfirebug and see if it spits any error messages in the console.

Comment: So this happens in Firefox but not in the other browsers?

Comment: I got the solution. i am really very thank full to you Guys.

Answer (score 0):

The exclamation mark appears when you are allocating too much memory.

To diagnose this issue you could monitor the memory usage using, for example, a performance monitor tool like [this one](https://github.com/mrdoob/Hi-ReS-Stats). It will display your current and maximum memory usage (amongst other useful data).